# Is there a name for this property on a binary relation?

Tags: terminology, relations, order-theory

Let $R$ be a binary relation. Consider the property:

$$ a R b \wedge b R c \implies \neg(c R a)$$

This looks a lot like transitivity:

$$ a R b \wedge b R c \implies a R c$$

In my head I've been calling it "weak transitivity", in that it restricts the existence of "loops" (i.e. $a R b \wedge b R c \wedge c R a$), but it allows more types of relations than transitivity.

I have figured that if the relation is also asymmetric, then this property and transitivity imply each other. But they are not equivalent in the general case. For example, let $P$ be the relation "is a parent of." $P$ satisfies the unnamed property, but is not transitive. if $a P b$ and $b P c$, then $c$ cannot be the parent of $a$, but also $a$ is not the parent of $c$ (they are an ancestor, but not a parent.)

So this property is not equivalent to transitivity. Does it have a name? Is it equivalent to the combination of other named properties?

Comment: If a relation is regarded as a directed graph, then your property is the directed version of [Triangle-tree graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph).

Comment: Huh, it looks like it. From that it occurs to me that this unnamed property doesn't rule out all loops like I thought, if you have four elements and the relation is only true for $a R b, b R c, c R d, d R a$ then the relation still satisfies the property, but contains a 4-cycle

Comment: Ok, I've just realized you had already made this comment @BlackleMori. =S

Comment: I'd call this *atranstive*, in analogy with the property pairs *symmetric*-*asymmetric* and *reflexive*-*irreflexive* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that *that* particular property has a name, but *antitransitivity* is $\forall a\,\forall b\,\forall c~.~a\operatorname R b\wedge b\operatorname Rc\to\neg a\operatorname Rc$

Comment: That's interesting, because if we take R to also be symmetric, then I think you can prove that antitransitivity and this unnamed property imply each other. It's like this property forms a "bridge" between transitivity and antitransitivity, depending on if the relation is asymmetric or symmetric!

Comment: I would **not** advocate this usage of the prefix *anti*: It is likely to confuse the property *antisymmetry* with *asymmetry*.

Answer (score 1):

You got me thinking about loops, and I came to realize that **w.t.** (let's call it that way, for *weak transitivity*) does not forbid every loop, only $\cdots aRbRcRa \cdots$ loops. You still can have w.t. and loops with more than $3$ elements.

For instance, let $R$ be the binary relation over $\mathbb Z$ given by
$$ aRb \quad \iff \quad b-a\equiv1\pmod 4.$$

Obviously $R$ is not w.t., since $aRb \wedge bRc$ if and only if
$$b-a\equiv1 \pmod4 \wedge c-b\equiv1 \pmod4 $$
and this implies $a-c\equiv2\not\equiv1 \pmod4$, that is $\neg cRa$. (Interestingly also $\neg aRc$ is valid; so both w.t. and antitransivity hold, but asymmetry too, in relation to your comments).

Nevertheless, coming back to loops, this relation does make larger loops, since 
$$aRb\wedge bRc \wedge cRd \quad \iff$$
$$\iff \quad b-a\equiv1 \pmod4 \wedge c-b\equiv1 \pmod4 \wedge d-c\equiv1 \pmod4 \quad \implies$$
$$\implies \quad a-d=(a-b)+(b-c)+(c-d) \equiv -3\equiv 1 \pmod4$$
so $dRa$.

Anyway, we still have $\neg aRd$.